# assets not loading on local wamp server using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wampserver

I'm trying to run a system locally which is built using php. after doing all the configuration the system gets loaded and shown in the browser but all the assets related to UI components are not displayed. I tried different ways to solve it by changing permission in httpd.config file but still it doesn't work. I'm new to php can someone help me with this?

.htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(assets|css|js|paging|test|cronjobs|documents|SOAP|PDF|demo|pages|classes|UPLOADS|HTML|company_logo)/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|gif|png|js|robots.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ index.php?&pageid=$1&id=$2&fm=$3&tpe=$4&curPage=$5&sortby=$6&sortbyodr=$7 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ main.php?&pageid=$1&id=$2&fm=$3&tpe=$4&curPage=$5&sortby=$6 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ index.php?&pageid=$1&id=$2&fm=$3&tpe=$4&curPage=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ index.php?&pageid=$1&id=$2&fm=$3&tpe=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ index.php?&pageid=$1&id=$2&fm=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?$ index.php?&pageid=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?$ index.php?&pageid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please try (1) removing this .htaccess file, and (2) changing all the UI files in your web folder to be read-allowed

Comment: What urls do not work, and what does ‘doesn’t  work’ actually mean  - what is the response if you request that url directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to route all non existent files on index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

If it works, try to get your GET Parameters